# ALM Workflow - Script Editor - Update custom field on Refresh of Execution Grid

Tags: hp-alm

In HP ALM, using the Script Editor in Workflow, I created some code to count the number of fails for a selected test in the Test Execution grid.  This calculation updates in the TestSetTests_MoveTo module. Not the most elegant solution since the user has to click every line to update, but it works.

My lead wants to have all of the values update on using the ALM Refresh button on the same page.  I am looking through all of the different modules, but I don't see anywhere that I can add an update on refresh.  Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to add functionality to the refresh button.  I created a message box that showed the Action being performed when it was clicked.  It's ExecutionGrid.RefeshAllExecGrid Then I added an if statement on ActionName to call my update code and it worked.  Hopefully, this helps someone else.

**The misspelling is correct, unfortunately.